# Overwrite instead of combine results of bmesh's convex hull operator

Tags: python, bmesh

When using bpy.ops with the convex hull operation as shown below, the mush comes out combined, but I want it instead to have the convex hull only. Can you see what I'm missing in my script? See image for the current and desired results.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from math import radians
def convex_hull(obj):
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')

    mesh = obj.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)

    bmesh.ops.convex_hull(bm, input=bm.verts[:], use_existing_faces=False)
        
    bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

convex_hull(bpy.context.active_object)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The API docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.6/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.convex_hull) say

> Any input elements that end up inside the hull (i.e. are not used by an output face) are added to the ‘interior_geom’ slot. "

So delete those elements.

```
geom = bmesh.ops.convex_hull(bm, input=bm.verts[:], use_existing_faces=False)
bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=geom['geom_interior'], context='VERTS')
```

Unrelated to this question, but `bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')` is redundant.

**EDIT**
The above method produced a non-manifold mesh. So removing all faces and edges before running the convex_hull method seems to work fine.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from math import radians
def convex_hull(obj):

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    mesh = obj.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)

    bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=bm.verts[:]+bm.edges[:]+bm.faces[:], context='EDGES_FACES')

    geom = bmesh.ops.convex_hull(bm, input=bm.verts[:], use_existing_faces=False)
    bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=geom['geom_interior'], context='VERTS')

    bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

convex_hull(bpy.context.active_object)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @tetii. This successfully deletes most of the interior geometry, however, it doesn't remove interior edges that are connected to multiple convex meshes. If you run the script with this change, you can see geometry on the interior near the top and bottom of a suzanne mesh when the script is applied.

Comment: I've tried changing the line to include unused geometry with no sucess

bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=geom["geom_unused"] +geom["geom_interior"],context='VERTS' )

Comment: I can redcude to all verts using the following to avoid this, but is it the most efficient approach?
bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=bm.edges, context='EDGES_FACES')

Comment: @Zak Nelson, your method with 'EDGES_FACES' should have left unnecessary vertices. However, my method with 'VERTS' resulted in a non-manifold mesh. Deleting all faces and edges before running convex_hull method seems to work well. I'll modify my answer later.